# How Ignore Empty EditText?

Tags: java, android, exception, android-edittext, calculator

I have **6 Edit Text** that if the user inputs all of them will do some calculations, I want to ignore Empty Edit Text  so that my app will not crashes if there is no inputs, I find way but it's painful and time consuming is to put each possibility's for edit text. 
For Addition I find simple why just  check if the Edit Text is Empty put value 0,

```
Edittext.SetText("0");
```

So I can perform Addition if only for example 3 inputs given like `ed1=1, ed=1, ed3=1`

The **`edTotal = 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 3;`**

my problems is with other operations if division or multiply we can't set it to zero it will change the result.

And sorry still learning to code.Thanks for any Help.

Comment: oh, OK sorry for that.

Comment: So you want to bypass the process if the value is 0 or null or terminate it?

Comment: i have an equation that can be preforms with any inputs  like if total = (D*8) +(R*5) +(Y*6) if user enters only D and R only i want to ignore Y which is empty.i hope its clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote some utilities methods you can use. You will need to remove default value of "0" that you are currently using. This way in case `EditText` has no `Integer` value calculation for that `EditText` will be skipped.

Modify those functions for your needs :)

```
private void addValueFromEditText(EditText yourEditText) {
    try {
        edTotal += Integer.valueOf(yourEditText.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
        Toast.makeText(context, yourEditText + " has non Integer value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void multiplyByValueFromEditText(EditText yourEditText) {
    try {
        edTotal *= Integer.valueOf(yourEditText.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
        Toast.makeText(context, yourEditText + " has non Integer value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void divideByValueFromEditText(EditText yourEditText) {
    try {
        edTotal /= Integer.valueOf(yourEditText.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
        Toast.makeText(context, yourEditText + " has non Integer value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

private void sumAllEditTexts() {
    addValueFromEditText(ed1);
    addValueFromEditText(ed2);
    addValueFromEditText(ed3);
    addValueFromEditText(ed4);
    addValueFromEditText(ed5);
    addValueFromEditText(ed6);
}
```

}

**Edit**
Added example method on how to use.
Or you can simply iterate through your container which contains those `EditTextView`'s

Comment: Thanks you so much it's better than set to 0 .

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should take each editText and check if this is empty or not ->

```
int count = 0;
   if(!editTextFirst.getText.toString().equals("")){
     count += Integer.parse(editTextFirst.getText.toString());
   }
   else if(// next editText){
   }
```

with dividing and multiplying change your count from 0 to 1. Sorry if there is any mistake in java syntax.

Comment: i think this way i need to write each possibility then put the equations on else for each "if statement". if editfirst is empty else total = ed2+ed3+ed4....+ and so on repeat each possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method which return int value.

```
 private int extractInt(EditText editText) {
        return editText.getText().toString().isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
    }
```

Which says check if edit text is empty, return 0 or return integer value.

Use created method wherever you need it.

```
int Total = extractInt(youreditText1) + extractInt(youreditText2) + extractInt(youreditText3) + extractInt(youreditText4);
```

Comment: thank u for replay, if it's empty will return 0? coz zero in multiply = 0 it works only in addition.

Answer (score 0):

or you can make still your edit text the vale + 0 like `Integer.interger ("0" + editText.getText().toString());
    }`

or input `Toast.makeText(Profesional_5x1.this, "No valid values, et least please input two result measurements MUAC, Knee Height, and age", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`